# Running a bash script from a symbolic link. How to change dir so relative directories work

Tags: bash, shell-script, symlink

About the situation:

I have a symbolic link named `mycommand` within `$PATH`. It links to a file called `mycommand.sh` elsewhere. That file needs another file, lets call it `mycommand2.sh`:

```
somedir
|-mycommand.sh
|-mycommand2.sh
```

when directly running `./mycommand.sh` the other file is found. When running `mycommand` it isn't. Reason: Within `mycommand.sh` the other file is called as `./mycommand2.sh`.

How can I make `mycommand` working without changing all relative directories to absolute ones?

Comment: Where are you issuing `mycommand` in the two cases? A symbolic link from a directory will not change cwd, so it should work identically if run from `somedir`. That hidden dependency is undesirable, though: could you also link `mycommand2.sh` from the same directory as `mycommand`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not caused by the symlink.

If `mycommand.sh` calls `./mycommand2.sh`, it expects its current working directory to be `somedir`. The current working directory is not related to how the command was named or invoked. It's a property of processes that is set with the `chdir()` system call or the `cd` builtin command in shells.

If you did:

```
cd /path/to/somedir
mycommand
```

`mycommand` aka `mycommand.sh` would still find `./mycommand2.sh` in the current directory.

For `mycommand.sh` to find `mycommand2.sh` regardless of the working directory its is being called from, it would need to be modified like:

```
#! /bin/sh -
mydir=$(dirname -- "$0")
"${mydir%/}/mycommand2.sh"
```

Or if `mycommand.sh` does require its working directory to be `somedir`:

```
#! /bin/sh -
mydir=$(dirname -- "$0")
CDPATH= cd -P -- "$mydir" || exit

./mycommand2.sh
```

And that's when using a symlink would cause problems, as if invoked as `mycommand`, `dirname -- "$0"` would return the dirname of the `mycommand` symlink, not that of the `mycommand.sh` script.

To work around it, you'd modify `mycommand.sh` as:

```
#! /bin/sh -
mydir=$(dirname -- "$(readlink -f -- "$0")")
"${mydir%/}/mycommand2.sh"
```

Where `readlink -f` (not a standard command but pretty common) would resolve all symlinks. That assumes `mycommand.sh` itself is not a symlink to a script in a different directory.

If you can't or would rather not modify that script, another approach would be to create a `mycommand` *script* instead of *symlink* that does:

```
#! /bin/sh -
cd /path/to/somedir &&
  exec ./mycommand.sh "$@"
```